# Raise custom error message with RAISERROR in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, raiserror

In previous versions we raised errors in t-sql like:

```
RAISERROR 50000 'My Error Message'
```

In the latest SQL Server this syntax has been discontinued and replace with the RaiseError () syntax.

I would like to have a generic method of raising errors, and the best I could come up so far is:

```
sp_addmessage @msgnum = 50001,
              @severity = 10,
              @msgtext = N'My Error Message', @replace = 'REPLACE';
RAISERROR (50001, 10, 1, 'This error message is not displayed')
```

But I can't go and create a error message with sp_addmessage for every message, because there are 1000's.

What is the better way to raise messages with a custom message?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
RAISERROR('My Error Message',0,1)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that sev 0 means info message, not error, though.

Comment: RAISERROR ( { msg_id | msg_str | @local_variable } { ,severity ,state } [ ,argument [ ,...n ] ] ) [ WITH option [ ,...n ] ]  
You can find more info about the different parameters at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql

Answer (score 18):

Actually, `RAISERROR` has been deprecated in favour of `THROW` since SQL Server 2012. Go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx) for more information. One of the more amusing aspects is that it is Rais*e*rror and not Rais**eE**rror leading to it being called "raise ror" in some circles.

Sample from BOL:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestRethrow
(    ID INT PRIMARY KEY
);
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT dbo.TestRethrow(ID) VALUES(1);
--  Force error 2627, Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint to be raised.
    INSERT dbo.TestRethrow(ID) VALUES(1);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    PRINT 'In catch block.';
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `s%` wild card so that you can pass in any message you like from any of your stored procs:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.messages m WHERE m.message_id = 62000)
EXEC sys.sp_addmessage @msgnum = 62000, 
                       @severity = 16, 
                       @msgtext = N'%s', 
                       @lang = 'us_english'
```

Then in your sp you can raise the error like this:

```sql
RAISERROR (62000, 16, 1, 'Error and/or Business Error Text goes here')
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use the state attribute of raise error

Step 1: In Proc

RAISERROR ('Error: bla bla business check 1 failed', 16,5)

RAISERROR ('Error: bla bla business check 1 failed', 16,6)

5 = state. can use 1 to 255 for your purpose. 1 is used by system. 
Anything other than 1 needs to be custom handled

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15
state
 Is an integer from 0 through 255. Negative values default to 1. Values larger than 255 should not be used.

step b) in c# use catch (sqlException e)
e.state can be used to check

Above worked for me. Thanks to the different articles in different places