# Create Custom warning SSMS

Tags: t-sql, ssms-2014

I'd like to create a custom warning for every change in table design (like the warning about tables affected).
I created a trigger on database for ALTER_TABLE but i've no idea how to show an alert for that.
Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RaiseError in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944630/raiseerror-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

-- New message:

```
EXEC Sp_Addmessage 500021,
               10,
               'Custom message';
GO
RAISERROR(500021, 10, 1);
```

-- Replacement of Message:

```
EXEC Sp_Addmessage 500021,
               10,
               'Custom message... ',
               @Lang = 'us_english',
               @With_log = 'false',
               @Replace = 'replace';
GO
RAISERROR(500021, 10, 1);
```

-- Altering the message:

```
EXEC Sp_Altermessage 500021,
                 @Parameter = 'with_log',
                 @Parameter_value = 'true';
```

-- Dropping the message:

```
EXEC Sp_Dropmessage 500021;
```

Comment: And when you throw the error, you can use these messages.

Comment: @SimoneG if you found my answer useful, please accept it. Thanks.

Comment: As i wrote i want a message like the warning you have when you try to alter a table and this alter affects more tables. It's an alert that appears even in the design of SSMS. I want something like that